# Changing tab completion key binding to tab in MC

Tags: tab-completion, mc

There are lots of people wondering how to tab completion. This is not one of those questions. The question is how can I assign the tab key to tab completion? alt-tab/esc-tab is a pain. In the panels disabled mode tab completion works, and that is holding me for the moment... But I still want tab completion in panels to be tab.

I tried making `Complete =` tab under `[input]` in the ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap file, but this just makes both tab and alt-tab go to the second panel which I have disabled as my main purpose is browsing media.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should also change `ChangePanel=tab` to something else.